New Tag : legal
I think it would be nice to tag :

AESManaged Trade Compliance Issue in United States
How are state wiretaps obtaining plaintext from encrypted transmissions?

questions with [legal] tag on the Cryptography beta site.

Before doing that, it should be noted that there is current discussion as to whether or not "legal" is even on topic here (http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/206/are-legal-issues-surrounding-cryptography-on-topic-here).

If you really think that the question should be tagged with legal or any other, then flag it and select other and ask to moderators with appropriate reason.


Thanks a lot I missed that option.
